# How to compile Xdebug on Mac OS X for Acquia Drupal

Tags: macos, drupal, netbeans, xdebug, acquia

Need someone to describe how to compile a working edition of xdebug.so for the follwoing setup:

Platform: OS X 10.6.8 (64-bit) - PHP 5.3.4
Purpose: Acquia Drupal 7.4.4 stack - PHP 5.2.17 with Netbeans 7

I am not looking for the Komodo edition of xdebug, as I want to be able to compile xdebug by my self.

An up to date short bullet point description would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to here http://www.xdebug.org/find-binary.php

Paste your `phpinfo` html-source to it and it will give you short-bullet-points instruction :)